# Creating new types in Python using extensions

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I've read the documentation and coded up my own example based on their `Noddy` example:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/newtypes.html

This is a bit of a departure from using`Py_BuildValue()`to build arbitrary objects dynamically. It appears that the underlying assumption is that there’s a C structure backing every object instance you want to create.

Is this really the only (best?) way to create new objects in Python? I was hoping to create a new object and declare members/types similar to how you would create tuples, lists, and dictionaries etc. It seems like it should be possible to declare a new type, declare members and their types, and then plug values in field-by-field w/o all this.

I can't even use the structure defined by the existing API of what I'm gluing because Python objects require the compulsory`PyObject_HEAD`field. I have to define a *new* C structure, copy the relevant elements that were handed back to me from the API call. It just seems like a level of memory management on the C side that should be unnecessary.

Comment: Why not put a pointer in the type and point to the existing structure?

Comment: Yes, I like this idea! That eliminates any copying, but how do you define the proper offsets into a struct to get the members? `PyMemberDef` requires an`offset`to work properly.

This is what sort of confused me about complicated (nested) structures. I wouldn't know how to communicate this field in that case unless I defined my own flat structure.

Comment: Define [`tp_getattr` and `tp_setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/newtypes.html#attribute-management) on the type.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's another way to create types in Python. Perhaps you've seen it?

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        ....
```

I'm being a little glib, of course. But when exposing a C interface to Python, it's often a good idea to have a Python script doing much of the interfacing; after all, it's quicker to write Python code than CPython binding code. And if what you have is basically an opaque handle type and a set of C functions which create/operate on those handles, you can simply expose those functions as free functions, and use them from your Python-side binding code. (You might even be able to do it without writing a single line of CPython binding code, using `ctypes`.)

Comment: So, what you're suggesting is creating the scaffolding of the class structure in Python and then use the extensions interface to set the fields via an init() of some kind?

Comment: @ClintOlsen Well, `__init__()` or `paintMode` or `engageSpatula()`, depending on your particular needs. Also read about the `@property` decorator (transparent getters/setters). But yeah, IME that's an efficient way to bind to a native library which doesn't have a ton of exposed types.

Answer (score -1):

So, rather than creating a new type, I was reading up on manipulating tuples in piecewise fashion and there's a section on`struct sequences.` This is sort of what I was originally envisioning:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/tuple.html

It doesn't have all the power that a new type provides, but for communicating struct-like objects back to the caller with named attributes, this seems like a pretty easy way to go.

I'm curious what you folks think about this...